# BIND DNS: how to override RR generated by $GENERATE directive?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I'm running an authoritative nameserver for a reverse /16 zone, where every IP is mapped to a custom subdomain.
This is achieved by a zone file with 256 `$GENERATE` directives, for example (subnet 11.22.0.0/16):

```
$GENERATE 0-255 $.1 PTR $.1.22.11.rev.example.com.
$GENERATE 0-255 $.2 PTR $.2.22.11.rev.example.com.
(...)
```

This works fine, the only issue is that whenever we add a "meaningful" reverse record (`4.3.22.11.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR www.example.com.`) it will result in a situation where there are 2 PTR records for the same IP address:

```
4.3.22.11.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR www.example.com.
4.3.22.11.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR 4.3.22.11.rev.example.com.
```

For the most part this is fine, but in some cases we need to have a single PTR record.

The solution has been to "unroll" the `$GENERATE` block into individual PTR records and replace the offending one. Is there a way to override a generated record without having to expand the whole range?

This nameserver runs BIND 9.8.2 on RHEL6.

Comment: In which cases do you need specifically one PTR record and not more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$GENERATE` Directive](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/9.8.2/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2598430) only has two forms for *range*: start-stop or start-stop/step. Because of this you can't exclude one IP from the range, but you have to split the range accordingly, e.g.

```
$ORIGIN 22.11.in-addr.arpa.
$GENERATE 0-3   $.3  PTR  $.3.22.11.rev.example.com.
                4.3  PTR  www.example.com.
$GENERATE 5-255 $.3  PTR  $.3.22.11.rev.example.com.
```

Comment: I ended up doing this, it is the least dirty solution :)

Comment: @AndréFernandes Ah, I thought this is what you meant by unrolling. Yeah, splitting the GENERATE is the correct workaround.

Comment: @AndrewB, your explanation is still really good, upvote for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this unfortunately. You're stuck with "unrolling".

In memory, the $GENERATE directive causes individual PTR records to be generated. This can be observed by viewing the zone file received by the secondary servers after zone transfer, which does not contain a $GENERATE directive. There is no syntax that allows you to selectively override the individual PTR records.

An alternative is mentioned in [Chapter 8 of DNS for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/generate.html), which is to add a step of using `named-checkzone` to parse out the $GENERATE directive and replace it with individual PTR records:

> The $GENERATE statement is executed while loading the zone file and
>   will result in an expanded in-memory version of the zone being used by
>   BIND9 operationally while the zone file itself is unchanged. If you
>   want to see the expansion (you don't trust the outcome or you want to
>   edit it) the bind utility named-checkzone will allow creation of an
>   expanded zone file (including the $GENERATE directive(s)) which may be
>   used as a template (or skeleton) and subsequently edited. As a side
>   effect of using named-checkzone any unqualified labels (names) will
>   also be expanded to full FQDNs and any $TTL directive will be used to
>   populate individual RR TTLs. This may, or may not, be a useful side
>   effect. Assuming the zone file containing the $GENERATE directive is
>   192.168.199.rev (as per this guide's zone file naming convention) and the zone name is 199.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA then the following command
>   will output an expanded zone file to 192.168.199.rev.exp.
>
> `named-checkzone -D -o 192.168.199.rev.exp 199.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA 192.168.199.rev`

The downside is, naturally, the fact that your zone file on the master becomes much larger. At this point you're only using $GENERATE to build the initial reverse zone for you so that the individual PTR records don't have to be typed out by hand, and a shell script could have easily achieved the same end result there.

This probably isn't the solution that you were hoping for, but that's the state of things unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0):

Though you may not be able to make an exception within the zone that contains the `$GENERATE`, you can define a [Response Policy Zone](https://www.isc.org/docs/BIND_RPZ.pdf). A Response Policy Zone should let you [override any response you wish](/a/842370/15051).